# gdt and mov surge protection

Tags: surge-protection, single-phase, mov, gdt

greetings fellow engineers, i came by to ask you for help, i'm building a circuit that needs to be as resistant to surges as possible. I did my research, and make to this circuit: as it is supply by 110v ac single phase, it can be influenced by surges in the line or the neutral, so i put gdt's to take care of the rapid spikes, MOV's in paralleo to smooth the big surges and a fuse to react agianst slow pikes in current, as in short circuits. So as shown in the image, i did this for phase to ground, neutral to ground and phase to neutral, as this circuit will operate in situations that big surges will occur. There for, i would like to know if this will work or if someone has a better idea.

[image]

Comment: Can you define the environment better than you have? More quantitative? We know now that it's a situation where "big surges" occur and some are fast and some are slow and probably some anywhere in between these qualitative hand-waving descriptions. In some cases I can imagine, you might prefer [these gas discharge devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82LhG.jpg) on the primary side of a 50 kg transformer. ;) I think details may matter to a good response. So any clarity you can add would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And in other cases, all those MOVs are overkill and all you would really need are TVS diodes.

Comment: so, allow me to quantify, the idea is that the system could resist surges up to 1000v, 100a for 1 millisecond, there for, i intend to use that bank of movs 20d271k, and the gdt cg5350l and to finish it off, the fuse is a 20mm 5a slow reaction fuse.